# java custom annotation: make an attribute optional

Tags: java, annotations, metaprogramming

I defined my own custom annotation

```
@Target(value={ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation  {
    Class<?> myType();
}
```

how, if at all, can I make the attribute optional

Comment: Thanks; I don't know that attribute is mandatory to declare if 'default' is not provided :)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can [provide a default value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html) for the attribute:

```
@Target(value={ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation  {
    Class<?> myType() default Object.class;
}
```

Comment: found it before you, but I think it is fair to select your answer

Comment: @flybywire How can you say that you found it before Dan as you answered at 15:18 while he answered at 15:17 ?

Comment: Maybe Dan types faster :-)

Comment: Link is broken. Is this the right replacement? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html

Comment: FYI for anyone else passing an array of Strings to their annotation.  I found I was able to use `String [] names() default {}` to pass an empty array by default.

Answer (score 7):

Found it. It can't be optional, but a default can be declared like this:

```
@Target(value={ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation  {
    Class<?> myType() default String.class;
}
```

If no default can make sense as "empty" value then that is a problem.

Comment: If you need a default class, and you might actually need String.class as a value, consider using java.util.Void.class instead (as you can't instantiate or really use it in any other way)

Answer (score 1):

For Optional attribute you need to provide default value for that attribute you can provide default value using "default" keyword.

Note : For only one attribute you can use attribute name as **value**.
If you use your attribute name as **value** you can directly pass value like this @MyCustomAnnotation(true) instead of @MyCustomAnnotation(myType = true).

[See this example for more details](http://omtlab.com/java-custom-annotation/)